# How to pass props to Vue from another js module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to pass props from any js module to vue?

Props are passing fine between components for me, but not from the actual Vue app itself:

### *main.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


var myVue = new Vue({  export to other files
  el: '#entry',
  components: {App},
  render: h => h(App),
  data: function(){
    return{
      testSuccess:'this test was successful!'
    }
  },
})

window.myVue = myVue // we use window.myVue because if we can export to window, we can export to other js modules.
```

### *App.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div ref="app">
    {{ testSuccess ? testSuccess : 'prop not imported!' }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default = {
  name: "app",
  props: ["testSuccess"]
}
</script>
```

### *index.html*

```html
<div id="entry" >
  <app :testSuccess="testSuccess"></app>
</div>
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

What am I missing?

I understand how to do this with components.

I want to be able to export the `Vue` module into other js modules and pass meaningful information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `render` function for your root Vue instance:

```js
render: h => h(App)
```

You aren't passing any props to `h`, so the `App` will be created without props.

The template inside `#entry` will be ignored because you're providing an explicit `render` function.

So either:

1. Remove the `render` function from the root Vue instance. Note that the reason most examples use a `render` function is so that they can use the runtime-only build of Vue, which can't compile templates.
2. Remove the template from inside `#entry` and pass the props to `App` within the `render` function.

The latter would look like this:

```js
render (h) {
  return h(App, { props: { testSuccess: this.testSuccess } })
}
```

Note this can't use an arrow function because it requires access to `this`.

Once you're passing the props correctly you should be able to update the value using `myVue.testSuccess = '...'` no problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the explanation. I didn't understand the implications of using `render` and assumed it was for webpack. Both your solutions make sense and I'll read up further on `render()`. Interesting note on the arrow function...

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee It sort of is for Webpack. If you're using a Webpack build and SFCs then Webpack will compile all of the templates into `render` functions during the build. The result is that Vue doesn't need to compile any templates in the browser, which saves a lot of bytes of library code. Generally the root Vue instance is an outlier and Webpack can't easily compile its template, so an explicit `render` function is used instead. Otherwise the full version of Vue, including the compiler, has to be downloaded just to compile a single template.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @skirtle. This is well said and is now starting to make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, you cannot pass props to your `$root` Vue app.  However, you can modify the properties of the Vue instance and Vue will react to those changes.

In your example above, you could write anywhere (including the console):

```
window.myApp.testSuccess= "I've been changed!";
```

and the HTML should update.

However, the way you have written your components above mean that the `testSuccess` property is not being passed into the `App.vue` component.  Instead of making your App.vue a component of the root Vue instance, create them like this:

**index.html**

```
<div id="app" >
</div>
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

var myVue = new Vue({  // export to other files
  el: '#app',
  ...App,
})

window.myVue = myVue // we use window.myVue because if we can export to window, we can export to other js modules.
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ testSuccess || 'testSuccess is blank!' }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: { // doesn't need to be a function in the root Vue instance
    testSuccess: "this is the default text",
  ...
}
</script>
```

**AN EVEN BETTER WAY**

Despite all the above, an even better way is to use proper state management.  By placing all your shared state into a dedicated state object (or VueX), any module which has access to the state object can manipulate the state.

Have a read of https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html